# C# Google SDK Update or Patch User

Tags: c#, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-dotnet-client

Having problem using update User with the google Admin SDK for C#.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/update

> This method supports patch semantics, meaning you only need to include the fields you wish to update. Fields that are not present in the request will be preserved, and fields set to null will be cleared.

This differs from the Patch as patch won't clear fields that are null but only update fields that have a value.

Problem is that I have to pass a full Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.User class to the function which will contain null of even properties i do not want to clear.

example:

```
public User UpdateUser(Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.User gUser)
    {
        UsersResource.UpdateRequest userUpdateRequest = _service.Users.Update(gUser, gUser.Id);
        User updatedUser = userUpdateRequest.Execute();

        return updatedUser;
    }
```

Is there any way of modifying the Body in UpdateRequest before executing it?

**Edit:**
The UpdateRequest has a ModifyRequest Property that looks like this
I just have no Idea how to use it, any ideas?

```
public Action<HttpRequestMessage> ModifyRequest { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi there! I don't understand what kind of properties you want to nullify and conserve at the same time. Could you please provide some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as updating things to the concept of Null that is not something that can be done with PATCH.  I recommend setting it to an empty string.

You should also not be sending the full user object if thats what you are currently doing.  I am going to assume that you have done a [users.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list) to find the user you want to update and change something in that user, say the name.  Then you have simply submited the full user object to your method

```
UpdateUser(Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.User gUser)
```

This wont work as some of the fields you have sent as part of the update/patch are not actually writeable.

What you should do instead would be to create a new user object change what ever it is you want

```
public User MakeUserAdmin(Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.User gUserId)
    {

     var updateFields= new Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.User();
     change.IsAdmin = true;
     change.Addresses = "";  // will set it to empty yes not null but the best you can do with this api.

     UsersResource.UpdateRequest userUpdateRequest = _service.Users.Update(updateFields, gUserId);
        User updatedUser = userUpdateRequest.Execute();    
        return updatedUser;
    }
```

Notice how you just need to create a new object and update only the fields you need then send that.

Dont try to update every field, just update the ones that you know have changed. Dont include the id in the object that is not writeable either.

Comment: I have sent out a ping to someone at google.  As far as i know there is no way around PATCH to get it to set something to null.   But just incase i thought i should double check maybe google has a way around it that they havent documented.

Comment: This code you wrote will clear every property of the user as it is using the update endpoint as creating a new User class will initiate with every property on null. As the endpoint documentation says; "fields set to null will be cleared."

Using the above code on Patch would work but setting a property to empty string is not the same as clearing it.

Would prefer to clear it instead of writing an empty string to it.

Comment: Also at the time of calling this method I only have the Id and propertys that have been changed. as I rather not do a new api call just to get the full user object but if thers no other way i might have to do a patch with empty string or fetch the full user object. just feel like there should be a way of doing it. Forexample Google Classsroom API update has a mask option to select what propertys to write.

Comment: Ended up setting values as empty string instead of null

Comment: I have had the same issue before with all the Google apis that use patch.  The only thing i have been able to come up with i setting the values to empty string or false in the case of a boolean.